# と particle doubt

Tags: particle-と

> その NETFLIXさんが日本に上陸するにあたってちょっと このテラスハウスに白羽の矢が立ったと“テラスハウスやりたいよ”みたいなことを多分 言ったんじゃないかって
> 話です

Is と after 立った the quoting particle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this と is quotative and connects to (いう)話です at the end of the sentence. Alternatively, you can think something like (と)いうことであり is omitted after the と. Sometimes と at the end of a sentence can be short for ということだ, という意味だ, という話だ, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!